# What are the differences between parentheses and `apply`?

Tags: scheme

To call a function with some arguments, we can simply `(funcname arg1 arg2 ...)` or `(apply funcname '(arg1 arg2 ...))`. What are differences between the two ways? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the arguments for `apply` are given as a list. So if you already have a list of something, you can use `(apply f my-list)` to call `f` with the arguments from the list.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how do you unpackage a list, so that a given list can be used as arguments to a function inside parentheses?

Comment: @tim By using `apply` instead. That's why it exists. Where you'd use `f(*arglist)` in Ruby or Python, you use `(apply f arglist)` in Scheme.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. Just curious how to unpack a list?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "unpack".  You access members of a list using car and cdr and cognates.  Most schemes also come with a pattern matching macro which will (amongst other things) deconstruct a list.